# SQLAlchemy: How to deal with bulk_save_objects() in duplicate entries?

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, sqlite, sqlalchemy

in my project I use SQLAlchemy with `bulk_save_objects()`-function. For me its a good and fast way to insert a large number of rows in bulk. I have set up my database (currently SQLite) so that no duplicate entries are desired. When I am trying to insert a large number of items and I don't know if there are duplicate entries and I run the program SQLAlchemy raises the IntegrityError-exception that says, there are duplicate entries. Here is my question: How can I handle the `bulk_save_objects()`-function in duplicate entries? 
When I used the `add()`-function of SQLalchemy it would be easy to catch the IntegrityError-exception in a for loop and ignore it. But the `add()`-function works too slowly for large numbers of items.

Comment: In case of SQLite you could revert to using Core and use `tbl.insert().prefix_with('OR IGNORE')`, for example.

Comment: @ Ilja Everilä: In my case its a bad idea, because I am working with ORM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `bulk_save_objects`, I'm assuming you started off with the values in a list. If not, what you can do is convert the list of objects into a list of values first.

Let's say your list of [ID, name] has a duplicate John:

```
ls = [[1,"John"], [2,"Mary"], [3,"Jude"], [4,"John"]]
```

So John is duplicated, you want want to only keep the first 'John' value.
What you do is:

1. go through the list
2. store the name in a dictionary as the key. The key-value pair is: `"name": 1`
3. each time there's already an existing key (name) in the dictionary, do not store to a new list

```py
dict={}
new_ls=[]
for row in ls:
  if row[1] not in dict:
     new_ls.append(row)
  else:
     dict[row[1]] = 1
    
#now you can convert new_ls to a list of objects:
objects = []
for item in new_ls:
   one_object = Person(ID=item[0], name=item[1]
   objects.append(one_object)
    
session.bulk_save_objects(objects)
```